# How to download google chrome 32bit?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, crash, updates

I'm using Windows 10 64bit and the Google Chrome crashed after the recent updates from Windows. I'm trying the [solution](https://appuals.com/google-chrome-crashes-on-windows-10/).

1. **Using the no-sandbox Flag** - which is not working, I'm not okay to use it for long time even it works since this makes it prone to attacks
2. **Reinstalling 32-bit version of Google Chrome** - I'm looking for downloading google Chrome 32bit to resolve this problem. But the google's  [intelligent page](https://www.google.com/chrome/) always recommending to download 64bit which is suitable for my system OS.

Please assist me if you have resolved same kind of issues already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google does not offer older Versions of Chrome Refer this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1381356/how-can-i-download-an-old-version-of-google-chrome) for more information.